# How to open new application from my application in android?

Tags: android

How to open new application from my app in android?

I have the list of installed applications and i am showing them in the listview now i want to open that application based on the list item click how can i do this?

Comment: if you can list the applications, i find it odd that you couldn't find the way to actually launch them ...

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, the concept of "application" in Android is slightly an extended one.

An application - technically a process - can have multiple activities, services, content providers and/or broadcast listeners. If at least one of them is running, the application is up and running (the process).

So, what you have to identify is how do you want to "start the application".

Ok... here's what you can try out:

- Create an intent with action=MAIN and category=LAUNCHER
- Get the PackageManager from the current context using context.getPackageManager
- packageManager.queryIntentActivity(, 0) where intent has category=LAUNCHER, action=MAIN or packageManager.resolveActivity(, 0) to get the first activity with main/launcher
- Get the ActivityInfo you're interested in
- From the ActivityInfo, get the packageName and name
- Finally, create another intent with with category=LAUNCHER, action=MAIN, componentName = new   ComponentName(packageName, name) and setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
- Finally, context.startActivity(newIntent)

the link below is also helpful

http://www.ercanbaran.com/index.php/2011/09/13/how-to-open-another-application-from-current-application-on-android-different-approach/